# Does the h1 need to be the first semantic element in a header tag?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am using a [Chrome outliner extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/afoibpobokebhgfnknfndkgemglggomo) to check the semantics of my page. It seems to be a problem to have any structural element before the h1 in the document main header tag. I was thinking the order does not matter, but apparently it does:

```
+Document Body
  +Header
    +nav
      +h1 Main Navigation
    +h1 MyPage
  -Section
  -Footer
```

Does outline like this:

```
Untitled Body
  Main Navigation
  MyPage
  etc...
```

But when the h1 is the first element in my header:

```
+Document Body
  +Header
    +h1 MyPage
    +nav
      +h1 Main Navigation
  -Section
  -Footer
```

it does outline like this:

```
MyPage
  Main Navigation
  etc...
```

Why is that? Is the outliner buggy, or did I understand something wrong in HTML5 semantics? The W3C Specification does not seem to mention it: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-header-element

Comment: You might be overthinking it if you're going so far as to start a bounty...

Comment: @BoltClock i don't understand your comment sorry...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After revisiting the specs, I agree that the h1 does not have to be the first element. I suspect the issue is with the chrome extension you are using.

I ran the following two scenarios through [this HTML outlining tool](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/) and received the same results (My Navigation appears under My Header):

With h1 second element under header:

```
<body>
<header>
<h1>My Header</h1>
<nav><h1>My Navigation</h1></nav>
</header>
<section><h1>My Section</h1></section>
<footer></footer>
</body>
```

With H1 first element under header:

```
<body>
<header>
<nav><h1>My Navigation</h1></nav>
<h1>My Header</h1>
</header>
<section><h1>My Section</h1></section>
<footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: I get the same reaults. `<nav>` is sectioning content, so (if I understand correctly) it should be fine to use a `<h1>` inside there, even if the `<nav>` comes before the first `<h1>` in the `<header>`.

Comment: so i guess there is no good outliner out there for now... wish w3c could make a official one. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The [WAVE toolbar](http://wave.webaim.org/toolbar) add-on for firefox has an Outline feature that you might try as well. I have not attempted your scenario, but it is worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you defining another `<h1>` tag outside of your title of your page? The outliner is picking up two contending titles for your page and is probably why is being thrown off. Semantically speaking, the main title of a page can exist anywhere inside your `<header>` section of your page as long as its unique and defines your main title, though that is not an exclusive property of the `<header>` section or the `<h1>` tag (and opinions vary to that description but it is more sound). Proper outline is defined here http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outline.

You can write your main heading section using any combination you want, as long as it is properly understood. So;

```
<header>
<nav>
<h1>Title of Page</h1>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
</header>
```

Is fine, because it is properly understood what the sections of your header and title of your page are.

Here is an online [outliner](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/) that you can use to test your design. Your title section should be **first** above everything else.

Comment: In regards to the first line of your answer, HTML5 allows for multiple heading outlines within the same page. Having more than one h1 is acceptable and the browser will associate relative importance based upon nesting.

Comment: @mudfalcon yes, but the issue was multiple `<h1>` headers inside one section. One main header per section sounds more correct, semantically.

Comment: I agree, semantically speaking one `<h1>` sounds better. Technically speaking `<header>` and `<nav>` are separate sections per HTML5 and therefore explicitly define a new outline. One other consideration here is implicit sectioning which may be where this Chrome extension is falling short.  This MDN post is the best I have found on this topic [MDN - Secions and Outlines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document)

Comment: one is the h1 of the navigation the other is the h1 of the document... its that simple. Just like in this example: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element

Comment: Actually, the [W3C spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-section-element.html#the-section-element) says, "Notice how the use of `section` means that the author can use `h1` elements throughout, without having to worry about whether a particular section is at the top level, the second level, the third level, and so on." So by nesting an `h1` in a sectioning content element (`section`, `aside`, `article`, or `nav`), it acts like an `h2` according to the DOM. Now whether [Chrome *styles* it that way](http://chharvey.net16.net/test/headings.html), is another story.

Comment: @TestSubject528491 "it acts like an h2 according to the DOM" you know, i would have to test that, it does not sound very semantic to me, because why not just use an `<h2>` tag instead of an `<h1>`?

Comment: @Andres Ilich: You could. There's no difference between using `h1` then `h2`; and using `h1`, then `section`/`article`/etc containing `h1`. I believe that every heading in a section gets "downgraded" by 1, for every nested section it's inside. So a `h1` in a `section` in `body` acts like an `h2`, but an `h2` in the same `section` acts like an `h3`. An `h1` in a `section` in a `section` in `body` also would act like an `h3`. At least that's what [HTML5 Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/afoibpobokebhgfnknfndkgemglggomo) does. See my prev link ("chrome style") source to test it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element) a `<header>` doesn't need to start with an `<h1>`.

> A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading
>   (an h1–h6 element or an hgroup element), but this is not required. The
>   header element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents,
>   a search form, or any relevant logos.

Comment: It just say it does not need to have one. But when it does have a h1 its used as the Document title, but in my first example it does not.

Comment: Check the first example. It has a `<p>` before the `<h1>` in the `<header>`

Comment: `<p>` is not a structural element element. Its seams only to be a problem if the element before the `h1` is a `section`, `nav`, `aside` etc..