# lower level heading tags before top level heading tags? Best practice?

Tags: css, html, styling

What is the best practice if you need to do a lower level heading in your web page before a top level heading?

In your DOM, h1 should always be before h2, then h3, etc... right? But what if you need to do some kind of h2 tag at the top of your document before the h1? Is this bad practice? I'm thinking about building for accessibility.

Comment: https://yoast.com/headings-use/ check ..

Comment: As far as I know, h1 is your important heading. You are most certainly allowed to have subheadings h2-hx anywhere on your page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817117/does-the-h1-need-to-be-the-first-semantic-element-in-a-header-tag